# How to invert fill_between

Tags: python, matplotlib, fill

I am trying to fill the regions below two intersecting lines and above both lines, using matplotlib.  I can fill between both lines, but haven't found a simple way to invert the region obtained previously.  The only workaround I have is to created some extra functions (a low one and a min one for the bottom, and the equivalents for the top), which is a bit cumbersome and requires manual inputs (see below).  Any better solutions?

[image: Illustration]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Doesn't work
def f1(x): return 32.0 * x + 2.0
def f2(x): return -55.0 * x
xRng=[-1, 1]
plt.plot(xRng, [f1(x) for x in xRng], 'b-')
plt.plot(xRng, [f2(x) for x in xRng], 'r-')
plt.fill_between(xRng, [f1(x) for x in xRng], [f2(x) for x in xRng], color='g') # Would like the fill inverted
plt.title('Not good'); plt.show()

# Works, but clumsy
def fLo(x): return -100
def fHi(x): return 100
def fMin(x): return min(f1(x), f2(x))
def fMax(x): return max(f1(x), f2(x))
xRng=np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
plt.plot(xRng, [f1(x) for x in xRng], 'b-')
plt.plot(xRng, [f2(x) for x in xRng], 'r-')
plt.fill_between(xRng, [fMin(x) for x in xRng], [fLo(x) for x in xRng], color='g')
plt.fill_between(xRng, [fMax(x) for x in xRng], [fHi(x) for x in xRng], color='g')
plt.title('Complicated'); plt.show()
```

EDIT: swapping BG and FG colors as suggested by @Mad Physicist will work if basic case, but not if there are several such areas to overlay

Comment: Make the plot background green and use white to fill between?

Comment: @wwii. Depends on if you want to zoom out or not.

Comment: Ping me when you ask another question. I'd like to take a look

Comment: @Mad Physicist https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73451753/matplotlib-multiple-fill-between-invert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that [`fill_between`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between.html) does not do well with infinite values (e.g. [Fill area under curve in matlibplot python on log scale](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9488955/2988730)). However, if you're only trying to plot those specific lines, you could just invert the colors of the plot:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
y1 = 32.0 * x + 2.0
y2 = -55.0 * x

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_facecolor('g')
ax.plot(x, y1, 'b-')
ax.plot(x, y2, 'r-')
ax.fill_between(x, y1, y2, color='w')
ax.set_xlim(x.min(), x.max())
plt.show()
```

[image]

This is very hacky and won't work well with interactive plots, but it will display the plot you want, hopefully fairly painlessly.

[image]

A slightly better approach might be to set the background of only the region covered by `x` to a green patch:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
y1 = 32.0 * x + 2.0
y2 = -55.0 * x

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y1, 'b-')
ax.plot(x, y2, 'r-')
ax.axvspan(x.min(), x.max(), color='g')
ax.fill_between(x, y1, y2, color='w')
ax.set_xlim(x.min(), x.max())
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Useful, thanks, but I think this won't work if I have several such regions to overlay; will clarify question.

Comment: @MisterMak. Agreed. You might consider selecting this answer and asking another question instead, given that this is already likely to be useful to future readers. Your question represents a fairly common usecase, so it would be helpful to keep it as-is