# Matplotlib multiple fill_between invert?

Tags: python, matplotlib, fill

To follow up on a previous question ([Matplotlib fill_between invert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73447993/matplotlib-fill-between-invert)), I would like to invert the fill_between for multiple regions. The solution proposed for the original question, inverting foreground and background, doesn't work for multiple regions. Some code is below. Any thoughts?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Doesn't work: want to invert filled and empty regions
def f1(x): return 32.0 * x + 2.0
def f2(x): return -55.0 * x
def f3(x): return 15.0 * x + 2.0
def f4(x): return -28.0 * x
xRng=[-1, 1]
plt.plot(xRng, [f1(x) for x in xRng], 'b-', alpha=0.5)
plt.plot(xRng, [f2(x) for x in xRng], 'r-', alpha=0.5)
plt.plot(xRng, [f3(x) for x in xRng], 'b-', alpha=0.5)
plt.plot(xRng, [f4(x) for x in xRng], 'r-', alpha=0.5)
plt.fill_between(xRng, [f1(x) for x in xRng], [f2(x) for x in xRng], color='g', alpha=0.1) # Would like the fill inverted
plt.fill_between(xRng, [f3(x) for x in xRng], [f4(x) for x in xRng], color='g', alpha=0.3) # Would like the fill inverted
plt.title('Want to invert filled and empty regions'); plt.show()
```

[image: How to invert]

Comment: What would the result look like? There are a bunch of different ways to do this.

Comment: I think that the result from the other question expands quite nicely to fulfill this one, so I posted an answer to make that explicit

Answer (score 1):

You can use `axvspan` to set the background, and then invert the alphas of the regions you want to fill. Here is an example:

```
x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
y1 = 32.0 * x + 2.0
y2 = -55.0 * x
y3 = 15.0 * x + 2.0
y4 = -28.0 * x

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(x, y1, 'b', alpha=0.5)
ax.plot(x, y2, 'r', alpha=0.5)
ax.plot(x, y3, 'b', alpha=0.5)
ax.plot(x, y4, 'r', alpha=0.5)

ax.axvspan(x.min(), x.max(), color='g', alpha=0.5)

ax.fill_between(x, y1, y2, color='w', alpha=0.5)
ax.fill_between(x, y3, y4, color='w', alpha=1.0)
```

[image]

You can also make the entire axes object green, though you may end up wanting to adjust the color a bit to make it look the way you want:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'facecolor': 'g', 'alpha': 0.5})
```

Also, remove the line with `axvspan` in this case.

[image]

Both options will look similar if you set

```
ax.set_xlim(x.min(), x.max())
```